# TFS auto check out licensex.licx when new item create

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I was working on a .Net project with TFS2010. After create a new item , TFS would auto check out licensex.licx file. Try to check in it, but got unchanged warnning. Nothing serious but annoying.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this file in the same project with the new created item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out the file is what makes it writable [non-checked out files are read only]. This allows you to save changes if necessary.

For your situation, try following methods:

1. Go to File--> Source Control --> Change Source Control. Check that
   the Source Control binding are correct. You can try to **unbind and
   rebind the solution file again.**
2. This can also be due to the extensions you may have installed, try
       to open the Solution file after disabling the extension (Tools-->
       Add-in Manager).
3. Try to delete TFS cache by going into default
   `C:\ {User Profile Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache` and VS cache in appdata folder.